# Rails Exception Notification Plugin - Force send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I'm using the Rails [exception_notification](http://github.com/rails/exception_notification) plugin in my app and find it very useful.

However, there are occasions when I want to catch an exception and deal with it gracefully but still would like to receive the exception notification email. It only seems to send for uncaught exceptions it seems.

Does anyone know how to force send the email for when you've already caught the exception?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Here's the code that you would put in your controller to trigger the email.

For the [Rails 2.3 version of the Exception_Notification plugin](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/2-3-stable):

```
begin
    10 / 0
rescue Exception => e
    ExceptionNotifier.deliver_exception_notification(e, self, request)
end
```

For the [Rails 3 version of the Exception_Notification plugin](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification):

```
begin
    10 / 0
rescue Exception => e
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, e).deliver
end
```

For the [Rails 4 version (currently v4.0.1 of the exception_notification gem):](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#background-notifications)

```
begin
  some code...
rescue => e
  ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e)
  ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e, env: request.env, data: { message: "oops" })
end
```

Comment: How to do this from model, because I want to add rescue block inside the model's method. How to get request.env from inside of the model?

Comment: @DonnyKurnia You can just put in `{}` instead of `request.env`, although in the email there is an error about not having access to session and request data.

Comment: Is there no way to access request. I am trying to access it in a non-model class that is called by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Notifier is specifically designed for catching uncaught errors.  Once you catch the error its up to you to send the email message yourself.  The quick and dirty way is to trigger the exception mailer code when you catch the exception.  I can't recall how the method off the  top of my head, but a quick look in the plugin should yield you results.  Look for the render_exception_in_public (or something like it) for the mailer code.